# Enable "." and "->" in emacs autocomplete

Tags: c++, emacs, autocomplete

Is there a way to get autocomplete to popup after typing a "." or "->"?

I thought the code for this was

```
       (add-to-list 'ac-omni-completion-sources
                    (cons "\\." '(ac-source-semantic)))
       (add-to-list 'ac-omni-completion-sources
                    (cons "->" '(ac-source-semantic)))
```

But it seems like this may have been deprecated.

The closest I've see is Alex Ott's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669394/seeking-autocomplete-functionality-in-emacs) using:

```
(defun my-c-mode-cedet-hook ()
 (local-set-key "." 'semantic-complete-self-insert)
 (local-set-key ">" 'semantic-complete-self-insert))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-cedet-hook)
```

However, this always pops up another frame to display the suggestions from semantic. I would like to have everything use autocomplete's native popup if possible, in such a manner that when I attempt reference a member function of a class using "myClass->", the autocomplete would popup with suggestions. Any idea if this can be accomplished?

Comment: I don't have an Emacs with autocomplete right now to test so take this with a grain of salt.  You could define the keys to something like `'ac-expand` rather than `'semantic-complete-self-insert`.

Comment: @lilbill39, looks like that's not working as intended. I used (global-set-key (kbd ".") 'ac-expand), which causes the expand to happen when I press ".". However, the editor does not type ".", only does ac-expand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry big oversight on my comment.  I'm at a bit of a loss.  In Emacs 24.3.1 with autocomplete 1.3.1 I actually see the behavior that you want with autocomplete and semantic modes enabled.  Namely, I get an automatic popup when typing one of:

```
someObj.
someObj->
```

I added this as an answer so I could list some code.  If it helps, my autocomplete setup looks like:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "<ac-install-dir>")
(require 'auto-complete-config)`
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "<ac-install-dir>/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
(defun ac-common-setup ()
  (setq ac-sources (append ac-sources '(ac-source-gtags ac-source-semantic ac-source-semantic-raw))))
```

It seems that the variable `ac-prefix-definitions` governs patterns which are prefixes to trigger completion.  The value I see is:

```
((symbol . ac-prefix-symbol)
 (file . ac-prefix-file)
 (valid-file . ac-prefix-valid-file)
 (c-dot . ac-prefix-c-dot)
 (c-dot-ref . ac-prefix-c-dot-ref))
```

`ac-prefix-c-dot` and `ac-prefix-c-dot-ref` seem to be the patterns which match `.` and `->` to do the completion.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've been looking for a solution for so long. It seems that I needed to add defun ac-common-setup()

Comment: @foboi1122, I'm glad to hear that it worked for you.